# Can' see all the columns when using describe() in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm going through a course and in the course, the instructor uses

```
data.describe()
```

to show all columns, as shown in the picture:

[image]

But when I use the same code I only get the following:

[image]

I've tried using:

```
data.describe(include = 'all')
```

but the result is the same.

Can someone assist me with this matter?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example of the problem?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem

Answer (score 1):

For me second code working.

I think problem should be your numeric values are strings, you can use `thousands` parameter for avoid it:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file', thousands=',')

df.describe(include = 'all')
```

Comment: I've used the following code:
data.drop(['Release_Date', 'Movie_Title'], axis=1).describe(include='all').
So I've excluded the columns that I don't need. But I still don't get all the values.

Comment: @FraneCal - Is possible use `df = pd.read_csv('file', thousands=',')`? What columns are omitted? Is possible some exaple of data in text?

Comment: When I use that I get the same as in the first post. Non of the columns are omitted.

Comment: @FraneCal - Not understand.

Answer (score 0):

Bi searching through the [pd.describe()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) docs, we can see that it says:

> Descriptive statistics include those that summarize the central tendency, dispersion and shape of a dataset’s distribution, excluding NaN values.

> Analyzes both numeric and object series, as well as DataFrame column sets of mixed data types. The output will vary depending on what is provided.

So if you have NANs you'd need to filter them beforehand. You can try using [pd.fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), which returns the same dataframe but with the values filled

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[0,1,2,3],
                   'col2':[4,5,np.nan,7],
                   'col3':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                   'coltext': ['A','B','C',np.nan]})
print(df.describe())
```

returns

```
           col1      col2  col3
count  4.000000  3.000000   0.0
mean   1.500000  5.333333   NaN
std    1.290994  1.527525   NaN
min    0.000000  4.000000   NaN
25%    0.750000  4.500000   NaN
50%    1.500000  5.000000   NaN
75%    2.250000  6.000000   NaN
max    3.000000  7.000000   NaN
```

Why, because the `describe()` method eliminates categorical values as a default. To have all values included you need to do `describe(include='all)`. By doing that, we get:

```
            col1      col2  col3 coltext
count   4.000000  3.000000   0.0       3
unique       NaN       NaN   NaN       3
top          NaN       NaN   NaN       A
freq         NaN       NaN   NaN       1
mean    1.500000  5.333333   NaN     NaN
std     1.290994  1.527525   NaN     NaN
min     0.000000  4.000000   NaN     NaN
25%     0.750000  4.500000   NaN     NaN
50%     1.500000  5.000000   NaN     NaN
75%     2.250000  6.000000   NaN     NaN
max     3.000000  7.000000   NaN     NaN
```

Why all the nans? because the categorical quantities don't make sense for continuous values, and the continuous quantities don't make sense for categorical values.

From what I can see in the image, you seem to be getting the data as text, not as numbers, thus the problem.